# C# or XAML With WPF

Tags: c#, xaml

I am just about to embark on a learning path in WPF. I want to make sure I'm starting as I mean to go on, by learning the correct skills first.

I have found references to WPF being used with both C# and XAML. I was wondering, in a work-environment, which do you use to develop WPF applications?

Comment: This is where you can start https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742119%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you need both XAML and C# of another programming language like VB.NET to create a WPF application.

At the very beginning of your learning process you can get away with only learning XAML. Which is actually a good idea anyway. Learn about using dependency properties, attached properties, layouting without writing a single line of code at first.

Next you can write some event handlers, but I wouldn't spent too much time on write too complex code attached directly to the XAML windows as the MVVM makes your life a lot easier.

For MVVM I recommend using a framework, for instance MVVM light from Laurent Bugnon, he also wrote some excellent books, silverlight though, which describe MVVM.

https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/

As I side note I should add that it is possible to create your GUI completely using code and without XAML. But I would argue that this is an exceptional case. The idea of WPF is really to seperate the GUI, using the declaritive XAML, from the rest of the application that is coded. As a beginner I wouldn't embark on the path of coding your GUI without XAML.

Another side note is that XAML is also used to declaratively create workflows using WF. So XAML is not used for GUI's alone.

Comment: XAML isn't necessary for a WPF application.  If you created a C# project and used procedural code to, for example, instantiate objects from the namespace "System.Windows.Controls", you would be using WPF with no XAML.

Comment: @user2588666 I would say that this is a rather exceptional case and even against the idea of a WPF application which tries to seperate the GUI from the rest of the application. But it is possible. I modified the answer to make it more complete.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. From what I can gather so far, the main features of working with WPF is basically being able to easily use data called through a C# file, bind it in the XAML and the combination of the two files make a useful application. Is this what WPF is, or is there another major topic that I've missed?

Answer (score 2):

XAML is a markup language.  When you write XAML for a C# application, it is simply instantiating C# objects.  So, you are really writing C# either way.

XAML is essentially a declarative way to write code.  It is extremely common for the User Interface (often called the View) of an application.

In my opinion, a WPF application's View should almost always be in XAML.  And anything that is not UI (e.g. the business logic, or the Model), should not be written in XAML.  This is standard for the MVVM Pattern, which is extremely popular for WPF development.